# Привязка параметра объекта к input в динамике vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Имеется перебор ключей-значений объекта `<div v-for="(item, index) in row">...</div>`. внутри данного дива есть инпут. Как связать вводимое значение в этот инпут с параметром другого объекта? Поясню, например в row ключи: 'foo', 'bar'; как сделать вводимое в инпут значение свзяанным с ключом 'foo' и 'bar' объекта object соответственно?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться директивой `v-model` для связывания данных c инпутом.

В итоге, данные вводимые в `input`, как и требуется *"связаны"* с нужным объектом.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    row: [
      { value: 'foo', input: '' },
      { value: 'bar', input: '' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in row">
      <input type="text" v-model="item.input">
      {{ item.value }} - <strong>{{ item.input }}</strong>
    </div>
    <hr>
   <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, но это не совсем то, что требовалось...

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    row: { 'foo': '', 'bar': '' },
    object: {}
  },
  methods: {
    addObject() {
      console.log(this.object);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in row">
      <input type="text" v-model="object[index]">
    </div>
<button type="button" @click="addObject">Сохранить</button>
    <hr>
   <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```